# Variety consists of complex matrices whose power is $0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the set of $n\times n$ complex matrices $X\subseteq \mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ such that $X^n=0$. What is a minimal set of at most $n^2-1$ polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ such that the set of matrices is the variety of $f_1,\ldots,f_m$?

I don't really know where to start here. What polynomials would all those matrices be zero on (beside the obvious zero polynomial)?

Comment: I assume that the question is asking about polynomials on the *entries* of this matrix $X$, rather than polynomials on the matrix itself.  If this is not the case, let me know.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom My bad, sorry. You're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $X$ is a nilpotent matrix if and only if
$$
\operatorname{trace}(X^i) = 0
$$
For $i = 1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Thanks.. sure, so we get $n$ polynomials from those relations. How can we know it's a *minimal* set though (i.e. we can't take out some polynomial)?

Comment: The key is to think in terms of the eigenvalues of the matrix.  We need enough equations to guarantee that all $n$ eigenvalues of $X$ (up to algebraic multiplicity) are zero, which is equivalent to the statement that $X^n = 0$ for some $n$.

Comment: The first $n$ moments of the zeros of a monic polynomial of degree $n$ uniquely determine its coefficients. The trace of $X^i$ is the same as $\sum_{k=1}^n {\lambda_k}^i$, where each $\lambda_k$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $X$.  $X$ is nilpotent if and only if its characteristic polynomial is $p(t) = t^n$.

Comment: Is there anything unclear about my explanations? I'd be happy to elaborate further.  Regarding the determination of coefficients: [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) are useful to this effect.

Comment: Thank you, Omnomnomnom. I think it is clear now. :)